# WPF Animation of DataGridRow Background color from transparent to "Current" (current is set with Trigger)

Tags: wpf

I'm setting `DataGridRow BackgroundColor` to Green or to Red with trigger based on `LogError` value.

I want to animate newly added rows with transparency.

This works fine:

```
From="Transparent" To="Red"
```

But what I want color to goes to is current color set with Style. Its not always Red it could be Green as well.

This does not work:

```
From="Transparent" To="{TemplateBinding DataGridRow.Background}"
```

or

```
From="Transparent" To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Backgound}"
```

Code:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property = "Background" Value="LimeGreen"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LogMessage}" Value="Exception has occured">
        <Setter Property = "Background" Value="Red"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>          
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGridRow.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                Duration="00:00:03" 
                From="Transparent"
                To="{TemplateBinding DataGridRow.Background}"/>
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Error message: `Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few problems in your XAML code.

**First**, you have specified default style under resources section of DataGrid and later provide your own style which will override default style.
Either you should define new style and set its `BasedOn` DP to refer to default style. But in your case i don't see `any use of defining separate style just for trigger`.

**Second**, you want your animation to go from `Transparent` to colour selected in style which can either by LimeGreen or Red depending on trigger. So, you should not set `To` value in your animation since it will automatically picked up.

This will work as you desire -

```
   <DataGrid>
      <DataGrid.Resources>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
              <Setter Property ="Background" Value="LimeGreen"/>
              <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LogMessage}"
                                        Value="Exception has occured">
                     <Setter Property = "Background" Value="Red"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
                 <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                     <BeginStoryboard>
                         <Storyboard>
                             <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty=
                              "(DataGridRow.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                             Duration="00:00:03" 
                                             From="Transparent"/>
                         </Storyboard>
                     </BeginStoryboard>
                 </EventTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
   </DataGrid>
```

Comment: You learn something everyday. Handy tip with leaving out the 'To'.

Comment: Additional information: Cannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object instance.

Answer (score 1):

@Den
You have to determinate a standart Color, before you animate. This is my Style for animating a row and cell.

```
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Style.Setters>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFF37C21"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGridRow.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="00:00:0.2" To="#FFF37C21"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGridRow.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="00:00:0.2" To="Transparent"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>


            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Grid x:Name="gridCell" Background="#00FFFFFF">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <ContentPresenter 
                                        Grid.Column="1" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontWeight)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.2">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontWeight)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.2">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <FontWeight>Light</FontWeight>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```